# How to remove error icons in Brackets

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, brackets

I cannot find any option in preferences that can hide this annoying signs. I am coding Photoshop Script and errors detection works absolutely incorrect here. Any ideas how to disable it? It appeared in new Brackets version.

[image: Unwanted error icons]

Comment: What does the error-detections say? Are you sure it´s correct?

Comment: LenglBoy, yes I am sure it's correct. It's say something like "File is not defined" but File is default Photoshop Script class, also say that a lot of other stuff is not defined but it was defined in another included files. Please read carefully, I need to disable this errors checking.

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried the above answer, and it I had no success.
But, I did notice this little line in the brackets.json file.

```
"brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true
```

Setting it to false did the trick for me!

EDIT:

Here are some clearer instructions.

1. Open "Debug" menu
2. Click on "Open Preferences File"
3. In "brackets.json" set "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks" to false

Comment: 한국어: 디버그 > 환경설정 파일 열기 > brackets.json

Answer (score 2):

Dude, try this one.

1. Click the "Debug" on the menu bar.
2. Click the "Open Preferences File".
3. try to add "linting.enabled" to bracket.json and set it to false. just like this. `"linting.enabled": false`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Preferences and append

`"debug": false`

to `defaultPreferences.json`. This disables debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when opening the `brackets.json` file, the `linting.enabled` option was not found. Simply add it and put it in `false` to remove the error icons.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer to the original question after doing all the things previously suggested in the answer thread that all unfortunately failed to get rid of the annoying red x's and its probably due to being on a newer build of Brackets.

I removed them by:

File> Extension Manager...> Default > ESLint > **Disable**

Brackets Release 1.14 build 1.14.2-17770 (release-1.14.2 f71f00acc)
build timestamp: Tue Mar 31 2020 00:50:40 GMT-0700